# How to make a generic implicit class for any collection in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, collections, implicit-conversion

I want to write a method, which returns `None` if a collection is empty and `Some(collection)` in other case.

Best I can get is

```
implicit class CollectionExtensions[A, Repr](self: TraversableLike[A, Repr]){
  def toOption: Option[Repr] = if (self.nonEmpty) Some(self.asInstanceOf[Repr]) else None
}
```

But casting `.asInstanceOf[Repr]` seems wrong. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some other approaches you can use in addition to @dk14 answer:

- Use an implicit class for `Repr with TraversableOnce[A]`. This will also support `Iterator`, because `Iterator` extends `TraversableOnce`, but not `TraversableLike`.

  ```
  implicit class CollectionExtensions[A, Repr](val self: Repr with TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def toOption: Option[Repr] = if (self.nonEmpty) Some(self) else None
  }
  ```
- Use an implicit class just for `Repr`, but request evidence that it's implicitly convertible to `Traversable`. This approach also supports `Array`s and `String`s, because they don't extend `Traversable` at all, but are implicitly convertible to it.

  ```
  implicit class CollectionExtensions[Repr](val self: Repr) extends AnyVal {
    def toOption[A](implicit ev: Repr => TraversableOnce[A]): Option[Repr] = {
      val traversable = ev(self)
      if (traversable.isEmpty) None else Some(self)
    }
  }
  ```

Both of those approaches preserve the original type:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).toOption
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> Iterator(1, 2, 3).toOption
res2: Option[Iterator[Int]] = Some(non-empty iterator)

scala> Array.empty[Int].toOption
res3: Option[Array[Int]] = None

scala> Map(1 -> 2).toOption
res4: Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Some(Map(1 -> 2))

scala> "123".toOption
res5: Option[String] = Some(123)

scala> "".toOption
res6: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to recover original `Repr` type, you can use `self.repr` ([scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html#repr:Repr))

```
implicit class CollectionExtensions[A, Repr](self: TraversableLike[A, Repr]){
  def toOption: Option[Repr] = if (self.nonEmpty) Some(self.repr) else None
}
```

If you would just stick with  `Option[TraversableLike[A, Repr]]` as @chengpohi's answer suggests, operations like `map` on it (`list.toOption.map(_.map(x => x))`) would return you `Option[Traversable[T]]` loosing the original `Repr` type (like `List[Int]`). `repr` helps with that:

> def repr: Repr
>
> The collection of type traversable collection underlying this
>   TraversableLike object. By default this is implemented as the
>   TraversableLike object itself, but this can be overridden.

---

However, the funny thing is, if you look at `repr`'s code ([here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L87)):

```
def repr: Repr = this.asInstanceOf[Repr]
```

It does same thing, but at least it wrapped (hidden?) nicely in scala-library and more abstract, so by using it you could account for potential redefinitions.

---

Also, it worth mentioning that this non-empty-collection approach is popular in scalaz/cats:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> List(1, 2, 3).toNel
res8: Option[scalaz.NonEmptyList[Int]] = Some(NonEmptyList(1, 2, 3))

scala> nil[Int].toNel
res9: Option[scalaz.NonEmptyList[Int]] = None
```

`toNel` here means `toNonEmptyList`, so it's not as abstract as your solution. Cats have `OneAnd[A,Repr]` and some helpful implicits. See http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/oneand.html